# Send information from one page to another with OpenSSO/AM and the get method

Tags: iis, single-sign-on, web, opensso, openam

I have a web site protected by an OpenAm Server and accessing pages, after authentication, works fine.  But when I try to redirect to a page and pass information with the get method, I obtain a forbidden access message.

Is there a way to pass my informations from the source page to my destination page with the get method (or any other method) or is there any configuration to do, to the Web Agent, in order to avoid the OpenSSO Server to deny my accesses.

I actually use IIS 7.0 and the last Web Agent version 3.0.4.

Thanks a million for any incoming answers

Comment: See related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487584/opensso-openam-turn-off-url-enforcement

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking why you get denied when passing params in a GET request.  You need a policy that covers mysite.com/*  as well as mysite.com/*?*

The policy engine allows restriction on incoming urls if they have args